# c# windows form application crashes

Tags: c#, random, messagebox

I got a function that generates a random number (0-97), and I've made it so it never repeats the numbers.

But my application crashes when all numbers have been used instead of displaying a **MessageBox**. Any help ?

"#" means that the number was already chosen.

Function for random number:

```
    private int RandomJeton()
    {
        int i, ok = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= 97; i++)
            if (!Sac[i].Equals("#")) ok = 1;
        if (ok == 1)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int poz = r.Next(0, 97);
            while (String.Equals(Sac[poz], "#"))
                poz = r.Next(0, 97);
            return poz;
        }
        else return 101;
    }
```

Function that uses the random number generator:

```
   private void button_RClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            int x = RandomJeton();
            if (x == 101) { MessageBox.Show("Ai ramas fara jetoane", "Oops!"); ((Button)sender).Visible = false; }
            else
            {
                ((Button)sender).Text = Sac[x];
                Sac[x] = "#";
            }
        }
        copySuportCaBackup();
    }
```

Comment: can you past the error log?

Comment: there's none.. it just keeps running without recieving any commands untill i close it from task manager.

Comment: Pick 3 unique random numbers between 1 and 3.  Now pick another one.

Comment: That's what the "ok" is for... if there are any more numbers to pick, pick one, else return something that tells me there are no more numbers to be picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, the maximum number of random is exclusive.So in this loop:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 97; i++)
```

You are iterating over until the `Sac[97]`, but you never assign a value to `Sac[97]` because you never return `97` from your function.`r.Next(0, 97);` will return `96` max.So your while loop never ends after all of your items become equal to `#`. You need to change `r.Next(0, 97);` to `r.Next(0, 98);` or `i <= 97;`  to `i < 97;`

Comment: Thank you! I thought .Next(x,y); picked a number from the interval [x,y].